# Inserting a string in a record....php...mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, function, insert

My supervisor gave me an assignment on PHP and SQL, and I've tried to solve it, but all to no avail. How can I update the records on my table, by adding a string into the specified field? For example, if the record in a column/field is 'P000M000D000'. How can I add a '0' before the 'M' or 'D' without replacing the entire string. An UPDATE query would replace the entire record in that column with the added string, and I don't want that.

Does anyone know the string function I need to use?

Kelvin

Comment: @kelvin How do you propose to update the records in the table without using an UPDATE query?

Comment: @Jordan, that's why I asked here, because I don't know  and my boss knows I don't as well

Comment: @Kelvin Ah, sorry, I jumped to the wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a lot of nifty string functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

The approach I would use is to use `M` and `D` as a separator and extract the part before and after using substring_index.
Note that `substring_index` is **case-sensitive**.

```
SET @sampledata = 'P111M2222D3333';
UPDATE table1 
SET col1 
    = CONCAT(substring_index(@sampledata, 'M', 1), '0M'                    /*P1110M*/
            ,substring_index(substring_index(@sampledata, 'D', 1), 'M',-1) /*222*/
            ,'0D' ,substring_index(@sampledata, 'D',-1))                   /*0D333*/
WHERE col2 = 1234;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a beginner I recommend that do it in three steps:

***1. Retrieve the field from the table you want to update.***

```
$query  = "SELECT name FROM contact where uid=123";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$name=$row['name'];
```

***2. Use PHP string functions to modify the value in whatever way you want to.***

```
$fname = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $name); //splits on any number of space chars
```

***3. Use a simple Update query.***

```
$query  = "update contact set name='$fname' where uid=123";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: That requires pinging the DB-server twice, not a good thing for performance.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `replace` function where you can specify a search string and a replacement string within a column.  Be sure to constrain with a `where` clause.

```
update tablename set colname = replace(colname,searchstring,replacestring) where something=something
```

`replace` is documented in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Comment: Hey Jeff, Thanks for the response. could you expatiate a bit. I'm a bit new to these languages. so I'm meant to replace 'searchstring', 'replacestring' and 'something' with what? (see my example above)